# Pre process images in tensorflow queue

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, queue, tensorflow

I am loading multiple jpeg images in tensorflow queue. The image files are all of different dimensions so I am using wholefileReader() to read my image files. I want to resize and crop the image_file through prep_image function but can't figure out how to do that.
Moreover, how can I get input batch through queue runner and process all that batch and run my classifier on it.

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once("path_to_image_files"))

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

_, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)
image = prep_image(image)

with tf.Session() as sess:
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
image_ = sess.run([image])
print(type(image_))
print image_
image1 = prep_image(image_)
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: You could use `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` as in the CIFAR [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L233)

Comment: This function always results in value error \'image'\ must be fully defined.
Moreover, how can I assign labels to my decoded image tensors? The labels are in a separate list/array?